# What dictates an item being considered "worn or carried"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If a stranger sleight of hands a feather into one of your player's hats/helmet, does that feather count as being worn or carried by the player?  If so or if not, can a spell like [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) be cast on that feather?

> If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and moves with it. Completely covering the source of the darkness with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the darkness.

What about an arrow that was fired and lodged into an enemy, or an object being held by your own *mage hand*? (*Mage hand* is not a concentration spell.)

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [What items are considered “worn or carried”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120716/4092)

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. I edited your question to hopefully improve readability but feel free to revert or [edit] further if you didn't like any of the changes. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119611/if-i-cast-darkness-on-an-item-and-then-leave-it-somewhere-or-give-it-to-someone?rq=1  This is Related, and awnsers the 2nd part of your question.  Welcome to the site!  ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's worded that way so you can't just cast darkness on the guard's fullplate, and leave him trapped.

I don't see a reason you couldn't cast it on the feather, but it would need to be cast before it was hidden on the other person, because after that point, it would be carried by that person.

The arrow lodged in an enemy is probably up to DM call; it could be argued that it is now being carried.

I don't see any reason why the magehand scenario wouldn't work though.

Answer (score -1):

Much of an RPG's rules and mechanics relies on the "common" vernacular without explicitly giving a definition or in-game mechanic.  If all else fails, consult a dictionary if you need a specific word-by-word ruling for those difficult players or DM's.

Typically, you consider things in your player inventory as being worn or carried. Even if you don't know they are there. If you carry a box of nick nacks, you are also considered carrying everything inside of that box.  If you really want to nitpick it, you 'wear' ear rings inside your earlobes, and nose rings inside your septum.   So in this case, you could argue that you are "Carrying" an arrow head inside your skull.

You CAN cast either "Light" or "Darkness" on an object first, and THEN place it onto a character without an issue.  The object being worn or carried can't originate in someone elses inventory (If I'm understanding the question / application correctly).

In the case of a "Darkness" arrow, is the entire arrow lodged in the enemy?  Does the spell affect the entire arrow of just the Arrowhead? Or just the quillions (feathers)?  To nitpick at this level will end up being at the DM discression ruling each time.